# Good ways to visualize code coverage results

Tags: python, visualization, code-coverage

I have a large codebase in Python, and a large number of test cases. My code coverage results (just statement coverage) are of the format file-linenumber -> testcases that cover this line.

What would be a good way to immediately visualize this data? Is there some module in Python (or any other language) that would accept the results that I have and visualize the data easily? I don't mind if the visualization/analysis tool costs money.

Comment: Latest PyCharm ([EAP of 2.0](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2011/10/new-pycharm-2-0-eap-build-cython-coffeescript-code-coverage/)) features a code coverage UI.

Answer (score 2):

Latest PyCharm (EAP of 2.0 - http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2011/10/new-pycharm-2-0-eap-build-cython-coffeescript-code-coverage/) features a code coverage UI

Answer (score 1):

[Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) includes simple visualization with [htmlpublisher](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) (?) plugin.